# Player lagging through the world but TPS and RAM usage are good

Tags: minecraft, lag, bukkit

On my Minecraft multiplayer server, I have a game called Destruction.
In there the goal is to survive several natural disasters coded within the plugin.

I use the plugin `FastAsyncWorldedit` to process the block management in the different disasters.

Other stuff I made with async tasks if it was possible.

Now my problem is, that even at 2 players playing it, they are lagging through the world.

(The world is a custom built map 150x150 blocks) TPS is nearly constant at `20*` ticks and RAM usage is also not overused.

Does someone know why the hell it still lags from the players view?

Comment: This can be (i'm not sure at all) because of some Minecraft client's limitations ? Like a rate limit ?
If you're sending too many async shit to the player, it might be the cause.. i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is FastAsyncWorldEdit. I used that plugin for a while because it runs quite a bit faster, but it has one fatal issue: it's **indefinably** unstable. I know normal WorldEdit is slow and, in some cases, laggy, but it's a lot better that FAWE. Try switching it out.

If that doesn't work, try this: install PlaceHolderAPI, then run the command `/papi ecloud download Player` to install the extension. Then install some plugin that allows usage of placeholders. I'd recommend MyCommand. [Here's a link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2mdepocjspqcqwt/ping_command.yml?dl=1) to a simple command I rigged up. Place it in the folder marked commands in the MyCommand folder. Then have the glitching players do either `/ping` or `/p` to see what their current respective pings are. (Either reload the plugin or restart the server to register custom commands.) If they're above 100, it could potentially cause issues.